# How to represent a variable-typed constructor list with GADTs?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm implementing a small DSL for a research project I'm involved with. Since this is the example for almost literally every explanation of GADTs out there, I decided that this would be a good time to really get started on using them. The obvious expressions (arithmetic, etc) worked out fine, but my DSL needs to support user-defined functions, which is where I ran into an issue.

With no GADTs, the structure of my expression type looked somewhat like this (condensed to a minimal example):

```
data Expr = IntConst Int
          | BoolConst Bool
          | Plus Expr Expr
          | Times Expr Expr -- etc
          | AndAlso Expr Expr -- etc
          | Call String [Expr] -- function call!
```

Converted to GADTs, how can I express the `Call` rule?

```
data Expr a where
     IntConst :: Int -> Expr Int
     BoolConst :: Bool -> Expr Bool
     Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
     Times :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
     AndAlso :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
     Call :: ???
```

My first thought was that this is impossible without some super fancy dependent types, because there's no way to know what types a given user function will accept (also the return type, but I can fix that by making `Call` return `Expr a` and specializing at the construction site). I can force it to typecheck by "erasing" the type, by adding rules

```
     EraseInt :: Expr Int -> Expr a
     EraseBool :: Expr Bool -> Expr a
```

but then it seems that I lose the benefit of having GADTs in the first place. I was also thinking there might be some other `rankN` polymorphism I could use in `Call` (something something existential types?), but nothing I came up with seemed to work.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another GADT with represent argument lists using type-level lists like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

data ArgList (as :: [*]) where
  NilArgList :: ArgList '[]
  ConsArg    :: Expr a -> ArgList as -> ArgList (a ': as)

data Expr a where
  IntConst  :: Int -> Expr Int
  BoolConst :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus      :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  Times     :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  AndAlso   :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  Call      :: String -> ArgList as -> Expr b

pattern x :^ y = ConsArg x y
infixr :^

example :: Expr Int
example =
  Call "exampleFn" (IntConst 1 :^ BoolConst True :^ NilArgList
                        :: ArgList [Int, Bool])
```

You will need to give some explicit type signatures for argument lists (like in `example`). Also, the result type of `Call` (`forall b. Expr b`) is a bit awkward, but I'm not sure that can be avoided unless you have more type information than `String` for the function it takes in. If you had more information there, you could also potentially relate the argument types (`as`) to the expected argument types for the function. I think we need more details about the specific situation you have to go any further with that part though.

Comment: Indeed, without any connection between `b` and `as`, it is not very useful. It is similar to `Call :: String -> [SomeExpr] -> Expr b` where `SomeExpr` is an existential wrapper which hides the `a` index (essentially rebuilding the non-GADT original type). Still, without much more information on function names, this is the best we can do.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the solution I was looking for. By the nature of the project, I don't think we can really get more information about the functions at compile-time (this DSL is meant to model an intermediate form of a language like Java).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't need to go the dependent route for what you want. How about a solution where you separate both building and calling functions. This allows you to type your functions when building them, so you can have type-checked calls.

```
data Expr a where
     IntConst  :: Int -> Expr Int
     BoolConst :: Bool -> Expr Bool
     Plus      :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
     Times     :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
     AndAlso   :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
     Fun       :: String -> Expr (a->b)
     Call      :: Expr (a->b) -> Expr a -> Expr b

-- type checks
test = Call (Fun "f" :: Expr (Int -> Int)) (IntConst 1)

-- doesn't type check
test' = Call (Fun "f" :: Expr (Int -> Int)) (BoolConst False)
```

For functions with multiple arguments you can either work in a curried fashion with multiple calls, i.e.

```
 Call (Call (Fun "f" :: Expr (Int->Int->Int)) (IntConst 1)) (IntConst 1)
```

Or you could implement tuples in your language.